# Different output for same box-shadow size in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Why size of `box-shadow` in Chrome and Firefox are different?

`box-shadow: 0 0 4px #aaa inset;`

**Chrome:**
[image]

**Firefox:**
[image]

I've already try the following but it's not working in latest Firefox.

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #aaa inset;
```

How can I have cross browser box shadows in a same size?

Comment: That obviously won't work if you have the unprefixed `box-shadow` after the two prefixed versions...

Comment: As for the reason *why* the output is different... I don't know.

Comment: Can you put this code is jsfiddle to that we can edit and interpret our system too>

Comment: @BoltClock, Dude, thanks. But I know the first one.

Comment: @Arpit Srivastava, here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqtkM/) but you need to open it via both Firefox and Chrome. I add `box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa inset;`, it works fine in latest Firefox and Chrome. But I need to test it more.

Comment: @Tooraj: In your fiddle it shows `box-shadow` **before** the prefixes, that's why it works fine. It may as well not be there at all in that case.

Comment: @Tooraj but i check in both browser using jsfiddle my browser showing same size...

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/ check out browser support

Comment: Yeah I know it works fine. but I'am not sure about other browsers. I'am on testing. Thanks dude.

Comment: Box-shadow works fine in chrome & firefox no use of adding vendor prefix styles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox and Chrome seem to render box-shadow quite differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000456/firefox-and-chrome-seem-to-render-box-shadow-quite-differently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[w3schools says there are 6 values to box shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp):

```
box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;
```

Blur and spread are optional and my guess is that as you only defined three values before the colour, the 2 browsers were interpreting differently.

I got them to look the same (to my eye at least) with the following on js fiddle:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px #aaa inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #aaa inset;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of the same `box-shadow` style applying different shadow spread sizes between Webkit and Gecko. Quite frustrating, really, especially now that -moz-box-shadow is no longer supported, so it's no longer possible to isolate Firefox that way!

Comment: It might've been different 6 years ago, but the difference in behavior is still here and changing the spread parameter doesn't affect the box-shadow in Firefox. Meaning that your guess was wrong, if the behavior is the same now as when you answered. Did you test this back then?

Answer (score 4):

Firefox and Chrome use different renderers, and there's no easy way around it. As `-moz-box-shadow` no longer works, you need [a different way to write a FF-only style](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/):

```
.myThing {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #aaa inset;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    .myThing {
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa inset;
    }
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787345/115493).

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in Chrome (Issue 179006). Will be fixed in Chrome 73 soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced the same problem.
Try to think that all browsers have the bigger shadow and only the webkit have smaller.
So solution is:

```css
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa inset; /* for all browsers */
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #aaa inset; /* for old firefox */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #aaa inset; /* override for Chrome & Safari */
```

Hopefully Chrome and Safari will continue to support `-webkit-box-shadow`.

Comment: Fourth parameter is the solution bro. Check previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Shadows are different because Chrome is buggy since many years:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179006

This is expected to be fixed in Chrome 73 (March 2019):
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6569666117894144

The simplest thing you can do for cross browser shadows is just to create it with Firefox or Safari. Chrome 73 and later will display it correct.

Please don't use prefix-hacks for box-shadow. Box-shadow is unprefixed in all browsers since 2011.