# Firefox and Chrome seem to render box-shadow quite differently

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I was testing a box-shadow effect in both Chrome and Firefox and I was surprised to see a drastic difference in rendering between the two browsers. Notably, Firefox's rendering was *much* darker. Here are two reference images:

[image: Chrome] [image: Firefox]

The first image is rendered in Chrome 22, and the latter in Firefox 16, both running under Mac OS 10.8.2. I have no idea why the two images are rendering so differently. Here's the box shadow itself, same for both browsers:

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.7), inset 0px -3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0px -20px 200px -100px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

For a live demo, you can see [here](http://codepen.io/imjake9/pen/hbfFq). Mouse over the box to get the effect.

Is there any way I can fix this drastic difference in rendering?

Comment: This has been an issue for quite a while. I still don't know what causes it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167516/different-output-for-same-box-shadow-size-in-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: My guess is, that this is a component which the browsercompanies design. For example, Alert popups look very different in different browsers. If you want to have same looking, I think you have to draw and code it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a media selector for Firefox which will be using a different style. You will have to play around with it. For example, I reduced the blur, the spread and turned up the opacity of the last inset box-shadow. So the CSS for the **.box:hover** should probably look something like this:

```
.box:hover {
  box-shadow(0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.7), inset 0px -3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0px -20px 200px -100px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.box:hover {
  box-shadow(0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.7), inset 0px -3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), inset 0px -20px 130px -120px rgba(0,0,0,0.9));
}
}
```

For more media selectors and other browser hacks you can visit [BrowserHacks.com](http://browserhacks.com/)

Comment: I suppose that using the prefixes of each browser will be as sufficient so there is no reason to use a hack for this.

Comment: @xpy Can you give me an example, because I cannot understand you?

Comment: I made a fiddle of the example: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/hkJkG/ even if there is an unprefixed version of the attribute, chrome uses the prefixed one, the other browsers will use the unprefixed.

Comment: Correct. However, newer versions make use of `box-shadow`, instead of `-webkit-box-shadow` if you write `box-shadow` after the vendor prefixed property.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long standing bug in Chrome which is fixed for Chrome 73 (coming March 2019).

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6569666117894144

> Historically, Blink's blur-radius interpretation has been at odds with both the CSS and Canvas2D specs: Blink shadows cover about half the expected area (see linked bug). With this change Gaussian blur sigma is now computed as 1/2 blur-radius, as mandated by spec. Blink's shadow implementation now matches FireFox and Safari.

Note: This bug is older than forking Blink from WebKit. Safari ever had a different graphics engine.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179006

> So the exact formula to preserve appearance through this change is
>   R' = 2 * (0.288675 * R + 0.5)

```
R' (new)     R (previously)
Chrome 73+   Chrome 72 and below
1.5px        1px
2px          2px
3px          3px
3px          4px
4px          5px
4.5px        6px

R' ≈ 0.7 * R       for R = 7px ... 12px
R' ≈ 0.6 * R       for R = 22px ... ∞
```

Comment: As the comment above points out your answer is basically only two links. Would you mind to quote the most relevant part(s) about the change so future visitors can see the important information even faster?

Comment: Added some quotes to the provided links.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Chrome and Firefox use different html renderers. I think that the drastic difference is caused by the raga color, try fading the shadow instead.

Answer (score 1):

May be resetting css will help :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IteyC

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple box shadows so try doing this (also removes alpha from box shadows I have done this below for you to try)

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0), 
            inset 0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255), 
            inset 0px -3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0), 
            inset 0px -20px 200px -100px rgba(0,0,0);

-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0), 
                 inset 0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255), 
                 inset 0px -3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0), 
                 inset 0px -20px 200px -100px rgba(0,0,0);

-ms-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0), 
                inset 0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255), 
                inset 0px -3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0), 
                inset 0px -20px 200px -100px rgba(0,0,0);

-webki-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0), 
                   inset 0px 4px 2px -2px rgba(255,255,255), 
                   inset 0px -3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0), 
                   inset 0px -20px 200px -100px rgba(0,0,0);
```

If there is still a problem dou you have any fiddle or link for that so I can check properly

Comment: Don't use prefixes for box-shadow. It's implemented unprefixed in any browser since 2011 and Chrome's buggy rendering difference is fixed in Chrome 73.