# CSS box-shadow renders different on Firefox and Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, css

I'm thinking on relying on `box-shadow` but it renders differently even on Firefox and Chrome/Chromium. The difference is very subtle with low values, but very noticeable with bigger ones.

In [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DtxAl), you can see the differences arise when using negative values to make the shadow smaller. Left render is Chromium 25, right is Firefox 21.

HTML:

```
<div>
  Hello there!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  margin:100px;
  padding:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  box-shadow:0 80px 15px -85px #000;
}
```

[image: Differences with Chromium and Firefox, first example]

How can I workaround this problem? Or maybe I should drop `box-shadow` by now?

Comment: Chrome is buggy (https://crbug.com/179006). Will be fixed soon :-) in Chrome 73 (March 2019)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox and Chrome seem to render box-shadow quite differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000456/firefox-and-chrome-seem-to-render-box-shadow-quite-differently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers use different algorithms to generate the shadow blur, in Chrome the opacity of shadow pixels decreases more quickly from the inner edge of the shadow area to the outer, and since the inner 1/3 of the shadow is hidden under the box in this example, it appears to look as having different start color. If we make the blur entirely visible by reducing the blur radius and the negative spread distance by 5px, and replace the solid shadow color with semi-transparent rgba(), the difference in the rendering becomes much less significant ([demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nedzK)).

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising! Since I have to adjust several shadows, It should take a while to review this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `-moz-box-shadow` property for firefox, it will render better.

```
div{
  margin:100px;
  padding:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 80px 15px -85px #000;
  box-shadow:0 80px 15px -85px #000;
}
```

Comment: `-moz-box-shadow` seems to be completely ignored in Firefox 21 :(

Comment: Put -moz-box-shadow above the normal box-shadow. then it should work. see my edit.

Comment: It works, but it's the same as deleting `-moz-box-shadow`. That is, `-moz-box-shadow` seems to do nothing to me.

Comment: Okay. the below answer makes sense :) look at that.