# Different behavior of box-shadow in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css

I want to create something like this:

[image: result]

I prepared the following testing page:

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px red, -10px 0px 0px red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

However the result looks differently in Chrome and Firefox. From my point of view Chrome version is OK, but I don't like the result in Firefox.

Chrome
[image: Chrome]

Firefox
[image: Firefox]

Is there any way how to achieve in Firefox the same result as in Chrome? I'm open to any solution, it is not necessary to use `box-shadow` property.

Comment: Not sure there is a way to fix this. Similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465797/css-box-shadow-renders-different-on-firefox-and-chromium

Comment: Its a bug fro Firefox I think. But if you want I can create a workaround for you using `:after` and get the result as per your image.

Comment: @weBer I don't think it is possible to create the same effect using `:after` because in the desired result there is a gap in between each line, while using the pseudo elements will result in a filled block.

Comment: @KevinFarrugia I am creating an answer using `: after` for a parent wrapper and it worked fine so, please do check it and tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't [`box-decoration-break:clone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) what you are after?

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 0px red, -10px 0px 0px red;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are ingenious! I've already gave up, thought there is no way how to solve it. Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**As per your comment am posting this answer -**

Here is a **workaround** for you using **`:after`** to get the result as per your image.

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  line-height:20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position:relative;
}
.p-wrapper{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.p-wrapper:after{
  content:'';
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  left:-10px;
  right:-10px;
  top:-10px;
  bottom:-10px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="p-wrapper">
  <p>Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.
    Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text. Here will be a text.</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OK, I was afraid that it si not possible to overcome this issue in Firefox. Thank you for your effort.